# How to connect AWS Lambda and RDS in VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

How can I create this scenario:

```
- A private subnet-1
- Lambda in subnet-1
- RDS in subnet-1(same subnet with Lambda)
- Both inside the same VPC.
```

is the above feasible and is it a good architecture ?

I have tried implementing it only issue is, it's timing out. But, when the Lambda is out of the subnet-1 it's working fine.

My understanding is since both RDS and Lambda are in the same subnet they should easily communicate.

Comment: AWS Lambda peered to a VPC is not advisable in most of the circumstances since creating a network interface is part of the cold start. It can lead up to 10s in the function cold start.

Comment: Being in the same subnet isn't really relevant as long as they are in the same VPC. Please provide the security group rules assigned to the RDS instance in your question.

Comment: same vpc subnets have a default local route which allows them to reach to entire VPC, check your security groups for RDS and lambda , also check if you don't have the RDS dns name resolves to public ip instead of private one, it makes sense if lambda is trying to reach to public ip of dns and getting connection time out .

Comment: Does it work if you increase the timeout setting? What is the current value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly okay to have Amazon RDS and the AWS Lambda function connected to the same private subnet.

Some things to note:

- If the Lambda function also requires access to the Internet (eg to make calls to Amazon S3), then the VPC will also require a **NAT Gateway** in a public subnet.
- The Lambda function should refer to the RDS instance by **DNS Name**. This should resolve to a private IP address local to the VPC.
- The Lambda function should be assigned a Security Group (eg `Lambda-SG`)
- The security group associated with the RDS instance (`RDS-SG`) should permit inbound access on the appropriate port (eg `3306` for MySQL) from `Lambda-SG`.

That is, `RDS-SG` should permit inbound connections from `Lambda-SG`.

Comment: what if they've NOT in the same subnet? Do the same SG rules apply?

Comment: All resources in the same VPC can communicate with each other.